# 1:1 line on semi-log in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization

I'm trying to add a 1:1 line to a semi-log plot in `ggplot`.
Data is at bottom, plot code is here:

```
casr <- ggplot(data1,aes(x = x, y = y, col=cat1)) + geom_point(size=3)
casr <- casr + scale_y_log10(lim=c(10, 100000), breaks = c(10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000)) 
casr <- casr + annotation_logticks(sides="l")
casr <- casr + scale_x_continuous(lim=c(0, 300), breaks=seq(0,300,25))
casr
```

I've tried this

```
line <- lm(data1$y~data1$x)
data1$pred <- predict(line)
```

Then adding this back to the plot so:

```
casr <- casr + geom_line(aes(x=data1$x, y=data1$pred))
```

to no avail. Also tried `geom_abline` with intercept and slope, but didn't get the solution that way either.

Any ideas on where I'm going wrong here?

Thanks!
Mike

```
data1 <- structure(list(cat1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("LS", 
"SS", "UNC"), class = "factor"), x = c(164.67, 153.57, 108.64, 
84.09, 107, 93.82, 89.86, 115.48, 166, 101.38, 98, 109.76, 93.71, 
123.97, 99.02, 153.75, 76.31, 150.45, 138, 83.86, 127.86, 112.39, 
97.4, 136.67, 95.5, 116, 124.54, 142.83, 175.42, 260, 197.63, 
96.8, 174.85, 118.42, 113.96, 106, 64.91, 160.6, 79.03, 89.85, 
584, 114.38, 61.9, 97.66, 143, 177.16, 122.72, 108.5, 158.57, 
116.3, 136.25, 142.82, 104.09, 170.67, 69.11, 67.2, 65.79, 57.2, 
35.29, 35.21, 74.6, 75, 98.78, 86.12, 75.4, 34.94, 15.6, 105, 
45.98, 60.41, 73.33, 27.6, 46.85, 6.85, 84.29, 56.6, 54.68, 44.9, 
48.6, 17.3, 5.2, 63.88, 48.42, 51.64, 55.25, 39.3, 89.32, 68.06, 
128.68, 69.51, 39, 156, 18.48, 2, 22.1, 20.21, 4.25, 9.37, 72.77, 
71.01), y = c(8617.89, 6995.71, 16625, 20788.89, 18000, 28757.14, 
25112.35, 1197, 21200, 10186.18, 10400, 23078.95, 16464.29, 5679.46, 
19515, 11612.5, 7140.56, 8856.82, 21200, 19920, 38748.21, 6608.93, 
31095.83, 37666.67, 26515, 6950, 33302.17, 26400, 13446.67, 14400, 
11884.58, 101.56, 30730.3, 7154, 2914.35, 7050, 9804.38, 9145.32, 
577.75, 42200, 11700, 278.2, 5860, 7399.29, 22533.33, 25347.06, 
29364.38, 10675, 14518.75, 15431.71, 18850, 15612.5, 19577.27, 
30543.48, 101, 687, 1108.92, 554, 318.5, 492.52, 459.3, 425, 
469.94, 578.4, 323.33, 245.22, 1830, 934, 179.72, 109.2, 196.67, 
150, 397.29, 30, 249.63, 480.16, 555.86, 645.46, 441, 478, 149, 
116.44, 310.39, 97.06, 1289.73, 409, 1294.62, 105.5, 296.32, 
452.19, 249, 721, 363.8, 30, 344, 451.66, 127, 152.61, 327.73, 
140.66), pred = c(8476.96341457203, 7894.74145234903, 5538.05381607161, 
4250.34668340723, 5452.03183246389, 4760.70881786037, 4552.99719890513, 
5896.82843063065, 8546.72514518074, 5157.24918132035, 4979.959971202, 
5596.8005365842, 4754.93905066716, 6342.1495530877, 5033.46144881168, 
7904.18288957427, 3842.26678556084, 7731.08987377824, 7078.05713236596, 
4238.28262473054, 6546.1895020109, 5734.75042493073, 4948.48851378454, 
7008.29540175726, 4848.82889862925, 5924.10369372578, 6372.04743763429, 
7331.40236457651, 9040.82702663485, 13477.253473916, 10205.7954753711, 
4917.01705636708, 9010.92914208826, 6051.0385719762, 5817.10073850642, 
5399.57940343479, 3244.30909462911, 8263.4820284236, 3984.93739251999, 
4552.47267461484, 30471.8404793441, 5839.13075869864, 3086.42728325152, 
4962.12614533211, 7340.31927751146, 9132.09425314548, 6276.58401680133, 
5530.71047600754, 8157.00359749453, 5939.83942243451, 6986.26538156504, 
7330.87784028622, 5299.39526398921, 8791.67798874663, 3464.60929655133, 
3364.42515710575, 3290.46723217472, 2839.90086681476, 1690.6681467872, 
1686.47195246487, 3752.57313192108, 3773.55410353272, 5020.8728658447, 
4356.8251143363, 3794.53507514436, 1672.30979662701, 657.879819204238, 
5347.12697440569, 2251.38461310827, 3008.27316399817, 3685.95854705413, 
1287.30896755343, 2297.01822636358, 198.921065199622, 4260.83716921305, 
2808.4294093973, 2707.72074566143, 2194.73598975684, 2388.80997716451, 
747.048948553707, 112.374557301608, 3190.28309272914, 2379.36853993927, 
2548.26536141297, 2737.61863020802, 1901.00238719389, 4524.67288722942, 
3409.53424607077, 6589.20049381476, 3485.59026816297, 1885.26665848516, 
8022.20085488974, 808.942814808044, -55.4732155915088, 998.820607893382, 
899.685517028385, 62.5447497239641, 331.101186352951, 3656.58518679783, 
3564.26891170662)), .Names = c("cat1", "x", "y", "pred"), row.names = c(2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 
17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 
30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 
43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 55L, 56L, 
57L, 58L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 64L, 65L, 66L, 67L, 68L, 69L, 
70L, 71L, 72L, 73L, 74L, 75L, 76L, 77L, 79L, 80L, 81L, 82L, 83L, 
84L, 85L, 86L, 87L, 88L, 89L, 90L, 91L, 92L, 93L, 94L, 95L, 96L, 
97L, 98L, 99L, 100L, 101L, 102L, 103L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Is the issue that the line looks wrong?  Your predictions need to be back-transformed from a model where y has been log transformed, such as `lm(log10(y) ~ x, data = data1)`.  If you don't want that extreme x value to be part of the predictions either remove it before fitting the model or use `geom_smooth` to add the line.

Comment: @ aosmith - No, I can't get the line to even show up, so I'm thinking I have the syntax/construction wrong -- thx

Comment: Thanks AO, I had tried that already, with no luck. I 'm still missing something...

Comment: I can run your exact code with your dataset and I end up with a line on the plot.  I'm using R 3.3.0 and ggplot2_2.1.0.  In your situation I'd probably make sure I was working in a clean R session, check for other loaded packages in case another package could be causing a problem, and check my package version.  Also see if `geom_smooth` gives you the same problems - `geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE, aes(color = NA))`